# return the uppercase alphabets

Tags: racket

I am writing a function which can return the uppercase alphabets from an input string. And it works well when I display it. However, can anyone tell me how to return the output string rather than just display it?

```
(define (convert input)
  (define s(string))
  (for ([i (string->list input)])
    (when (char-alphabetic? i)
       (let ((s(string-append s (string i))))
         (display (string-upcase s))))))
```

Comment: it's racket it seems.

Comment: Looking to see if IntelliJ has a 'racket' plugin, lol...

Answer (score 2):

If you want to return data from a function, like you are here with returning a string, I suggest you look past the basic `for` loop to its variants, such as [`for/list`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html#(form._((lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt)._for%2Flist))), [`for/vector`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._for%2Fvector%29%29), [`for/hash`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._for%2Fhash%29%29), and [`for/fold`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._for%2Ffold%29%29). In this case [`for/list`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html#(form._((lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt)._for%2Flist))) can help:

```
(define (convert input)
  (list->string
   (for/list ([i input] #:when (char-alphabetic? i))
     (char-upcase i))))
```

Using it:

```
> (convert "ab1c23")
"ABC"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one possible solution:

```
(define (convert input)
  (list->string
   (foldr (lambda (chr acc)
            (if (char-alphabetic? chr)
                (cons (char-upcase chr) acc)
                acc))
          '()
          (string->list input))))
```

We need to accumulate the result somewhere, instead of printing char by char. For that, we use `foldr` to process a list of chars, uppercasing alphabetic chars and ignoring the others. This produces a list of chars that we convert back to a string using `list->string`. It works as expected:

```
(convert "ab1c23")
=> "ABC"
```